# QML QSettings and QML - Cannot save/load settings

Tags: c++, qt4, qml, qt5

What I do wrong ? I always have in debug console-"error! cannot load data". Can anyone point out an error? Maybe I create bad "settings" ? It's a permission program problem?

```
 //main.cpp
    #include <QtGui/QGuiApplication>
    #include "qtquick2applicationviewer.h"
    #include <QQmlContext>
    #include <QSettings>
    #include "settings.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QtQuick2ApplicationViewer viewer;

    viewer.setMainQmlFile(QStringLiteral("qml/kon/main.qml"));

    Settings* settings = new Settings();

    viewer.rootContext()->setContextProperty("settings", settings);

    viewer.showExpanded();

    return app.exec();
}
```

//settings.h

```
#ifndef SETTINGS_H
#define SETTINGS_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QSettings>

class Settings : public QSettings {
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  Settings(QObject *parent = 0);
  virtual ~Settings();

  Q_INVOKABLE
  void setValue(const QString &key, const QVariant &value);

  Q_INVOKABLE
  void setValueIfNotSet(const QString &key, const QVariant &value);

  Q_INVOKABLE
  QVariant value(const QString &key, const QVariant &defaultValue);

  Q_INVOKABLE
  bool boolValue(const QString &key, const bool defaultValue);

  Q_INVOKABLE
  void initToDefaults();

signals:
  void settingChanged(const QString& key);
};

#endif // SETTINGS_H
```

//settings.cpp

```
#include "settings.h"

Settings::Settings(QObject* parent) :
  QSettings(parent) {

}

Settings::~Settings() {
}

QVariant Settings::value(const QString &key, const QVariant &defaultValue = QVariant()) {
  return QSettings::value(key, defaultValue);
}

bool Settings::boolValue(const QString &key, bool defaultValue) {
  return QSettings::value(key, defaultValue).toBool();
}

void Settings::setValue(const QString &key, const QVariant &value) {

  // change the setting and emit a changed signal
  // (we are not checking if the value really changed before emitting for simplicity)
  QSettings::setValue(key, value);
  emit settingChanged(key);
}

void Settings::setValueIfNotSet(const QString &key, const QVariant &value) {

  // change the setting and emit a changed signal
  if( !QSettings::contains(key) ) {
    QSettings::setValue(key, value);
    // (we are not checking if the value really changed before emitting for simplicity)
    emit settingChanged(key);
  }
}

void Settings::initToDefaults() {
  setValueIfNotSet("test", true);
}
```

And in QML i use this class like that:

```
Button
        {
            id:button1
        nazwa: "Set value"
        onClicked: settings.setValue("1","adskmmads")
    }

    Button
    {
        id:button2
        onClicked: console.log(settings.value("1","error! cannot load data"))
        nazwa: "Load value and show"
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QSettings` constuctor needs at least 2 strings `organization` **name** and `application` **name**

```
QSettings::QSettings(const QString & organization, const QString & application = QString(), QObject * parent = 0);
```

In your case just use this code below in your `main()`

(1)If you use `QSettings` from many places in your application, you might want to specify the organization name and the application name using `QCoreApplication::setOrganizationName()` and `QCoreApplication::setApplicationName()`, and then use the **default** `QSettings` constructor:

```
QCoreApplication::setOrganizationName("MySoft");
QCoreApplication::setOrganizationDomain("mysoft.com");
QCoreApplication::setApplicationName("Star Runner");
...
QSettings settings; //default constructor
```

(1)reference: [QSettings](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qsettings.html#details)